# Event when page is rendered/all components are loaded

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have a Qml component consisting of sub-components. After everything has been loaded (rendered) I want to perform some action.
Is there a way to find out when all components are loaded? Just using the `Component.onCompleted` event on the root element does not suffice because the children are not guaranteed to be loaded.

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`afterSynchronizing()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html#afterSynchronizing) signal of `QQuickWindow` to achieve this:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 1280
    height: 700

    property bool initialised: false

    onAfterSynchronizing: {
        if (!initialised) {
            print("initialising...");
            // stuff...
            initialised = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Pros:

- You get it for free.

Cons:

- You can only use it on `QQuickWindow` derivatives.

An alternative is to use a [`Loader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html); specifically its [`loaded()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#loaded-signal) signal:

```
Loader {
    source: "MyComponent.qml"
    onLoaded: {
        // stuff...
    }
}
```

Pros:

- A much clearer alternative to anyone who may have to maintain your code.
- Works without having a `Window`; can use it at any level in your scene's "hierarchy".

Cons:

- Comes with a little overhead. If the component is constructed often, at a low level (like a button), it may be worth profiling to see if it has a negative effect on performance. If not, it's negligible.